# Are there tools to design and test experimental hardware and firmware through emulation?

Tags: microcontroller, development-tools, emulator

I'm a programmer and I'm interested in testing an idea I have for a SATA intercept hardware device.

I'd like to design a custom piece of hardware involving SATA connections, splitting of signals etc. My first planned step is understanding the protocol and firmware. Then taking a few courses, maybe guided hands-on projects via kits to get acquainted with circuit engineering. And I imagine all the parts I should need already exist. The only thing I really have no idea how to get started with is testing. it seems like before I build anything physical, there must be some tooling to emulate experimental hardware peripherals. There's a question of I/O performance and such depending on how I handle the protocol for my goal, so I'm hoping there's a way to test that performance with sort of a hardware design emulation system. It would be really nice if there were tools that could connect to Qemu to test integration.

What tools exist in the industry for this? Or is this sort of thing usually done physically in this field?

Answer (score 3):

A SATA protocol analyzer can intercept and decode the traffic on a SATA connection. This is a rather expensive piece of gear, but would be essential in developing a new SATA device. There are also SATA traffic generators.

FPGAs with SERDES capability can implement SATA, using their integrated PHY receiver/ transmitters combined with SATA controller IP. You could make your 'man in the middle' out of something like this.

FPGAs without SERDES could potentially use an external PHY solution. This would be the approach if your intent is to develop an ASIC using someone's PHY solution. The PHY would be supplied by the mixed-signal IP vendor.

Comment: Could you link or expand a few of your acronyms? I don't  know the lingo here. I know FPGA, ASIC, of course SATA, but SERDES and PHY I don't.

Comment: SERDES = serializer / deserializer. IP = intellectual property. PHY = physical layer interface (from the OSI networking model.)